# Are new open-source plugins for Eclipse available for MyEclipse out-of-the-box?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rad, myeclipse

I could not quite get a clear understanding of this in the web:
if someone develops a new Eclispe plugin, is it supported in MyEclipse as-is?
Or should I wait until Genuitec release a new version of MyEclipse that will also support this new plugin?

I want to understand if going with MyEclipse couples me to existing plugins, so that I won't be as open to new plugin developments as I would have been using regular Eclipse.

My dilemma is with MyEclipse Blue 8.6, Eclipse 3.6, and eventually RAD 7.5.
I'm only considering MyEclipse Blue because I want to embed WebSphere 7.0. Otherwise I would surely go with regular Eclipse. It's just that I assume RAD 7.5 will behave like a regular Eclipse (3.4 though) with regard to new Eclipse plugins (i.e. they will be available straight away).

I hope it's clear.
Thanks in any case,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

MyEclipse is a custom distribution of Eclipse, just like RAD. A third-party Eclipse plugin may or may not work with a distribution depending on the details of the plugin, the version of base platform that the distribution is based on, which plugins it has, etc.

There is no general answer to your question. It all depends on the specific plugin you are trying to install and how it interracts with other plugins.

One thing to be aware of when it comes to MyEclipse is that it does not use Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) to deliver Java EE and app server integration. Pretty much every other plugin out there in Java EE space will integrate with WTP. So if the plugin is in Java EE space, chance are that it will not install into MyEclipse or will not work correctly once installed. If the plugin is not in Java EE space, it is more likely to work without issues in MyEclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try MyEclipse Blue 9.0 for free for 30-days. Try your plug-ins first before buying is my advice. Go here: http://www.myeclipseide.com/blue.php